# Website Run On Bash?

Tags: html, bash, web, terminal

Would it be possible to make an HTML site that runs (with/on) bash mechanics?

I was just wondering out of curiosity because I started web development and security with bash/html foundations and I think it would be pretty fun to do something like that.

Comment: you're looking for cgi, take a look [here](http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/simple-cgi-and-apache-examples-on-ubuntu-linux) for a bash/apache example

Comment: I don't know, I kinda meant like embedding bash code into a web app example: echo(ing) a sentence onto an html page. like document.write for javascript. ill see if thats what im looking for, thanks again.

Comment: Do you mean embedding BASH like you could embed javascript into an HTML document? Like `<script> some BASH </script>`?

Comment: yes thats ideally what I meant but I don't think thats possible

Answer (score 0):

look for netcat documentation, this will serve index.html at port 80.

```
while true; do nc -l 80  < index.html; done
```

obviously, you can provide data from a script as easily.